# Redirect when cookies are deleted

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, cookies

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html"); //setting the MIME of this page

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); //creating a writer object          
        String sourceCookieName = "Username"; 
        String sourceCookieName2 = "Password"; 
        Cookie targetCookie = null;
        Cookie targetCookie2 = null;
        Cookie[] allCookies = request.getCookies();

        if (allCookies!=null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : allCookies) {
                if (cookie.getName().equals(sourceCookieName)) {
                    targetCookie = cookie;
                    //break;
                }
                if (cookie.getName().equals(sourceCookieName2)) {
                    targetCookie2 = cookie;
                    //break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (targetCookie != null && targetCookie2 != null) {
            //somecode
        } 
        else {
            out.print("<p><h1>You will be redirected in <span id='counter'>5</span> second(s).</h1></p>");
            out.print("<script type='text/javascript'>");
            out.print("function countdown() {");
            out.print("var i = document.getElementById('counter');");
            out.print("if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=1) {");
            out.print("location.href = 'index.html';");
            out.print("}");
            out.print("i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;");
            out.print("}");
            out.print("setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);");
            out.print("</script>");
            //response.sendRedirect("index.html");
            return;
        }
```

I have this servlet that will redirect to index.html when the cookies is are deleted. My problem is that when I delete the cookies, it does not redirect to index.html automatically I need to reload/refresh the page first before it redirect. How I will make it to redirect automatically upon deletion of cookies?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are deleting the cookies when the page is already loaded. You need to understand the request-response cycle of servlets.

A Servlet is only executed when a new request is received by the container. Once your page is already loaded and then you clear your cookies, your servlet will be only execute when the page will be refreshed(or a new request will be sent to the servlet).

Comment: So that's not possible for servlets?

Comment: It is not possible until and unless you send a new request to the servlet. Your request scope has been completed and whatever you see is already rendered and present in your browser. when you refresh, a new request will be sent to the servlet and this time your servlet will redirect if the cookies are not present.